# Chilli plant leaves droop during the day and is up during night

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, transplanting, chili

My chili plant leaves droop during the day and the leaves are all up at night. I water the plant enough and have cross checked for any bacterial infection. The soil also consists of vermicompost and seaweed fertiliser that I add once a month. The plant in general also shows no signs of growth.

[image]

Does anyone have any pointers on how to avoid this drooping

Comment: Is it in full sun during the day? Outside or inside? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: And there's no yellowing on the lower leaves?

Comment: I am in India, its not in full sun during the day its mostly in sun for 2-3 hours outside. There is no yellowing of leaves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it is quite normal for chili leaves to droop during the day and get up at night. It is most noticeable in young plants, and doesn’t stop them from growing. This as long as leaves remain bright and crisp. When it is too hot or they lack water they can get flaccid and dull. It starts with the tips of the lower leaves. I wonder whether that’s happening in your photo.

I have two young ones that are prone to get flaccid and dull in strong, hot sunlight, so I place then behind the bigger ones, so they get dappled sunlight only, see photo, and that does the trick. It’s been around 30 ºC around here (Setúbal, Portugal). Mine don’t like it much when it gets well above 30 ºC.

[image]